# Java MultiThread: unexpected execution time

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently checking the behaviour of multithreading in Java and I'm getting an unexpected result.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Generating 50 random adjacency matrices with a size of 600x600 and
   save them to a .txt file
2. Reading these matrices and running Floyd Warshall algorithm with N
   threads (from 1 to 3) without syncronization. Every thread runs the
   algorithm with 50 matrices.

Here's the result I get (total execution time with N threads):

**50 matrices of 200x200:**

- With 1 Thread: ~483 ms
- With 2 Threads: ~615 ms
- With 3 Threads: ~741 ms

**50 matrices of 600x600:**

- With 1 Thread: ~9500 ms
- With 2 Threads: ~15389 ms
- With 3 Threads: ~16383 ms

**50 matrices of 1000x1000:**

- With 1 Thread: ~43140 ms
- With 2 Threads: ~61408 ms
- With 3 Threads: ~76219 ms

Shouldn't the times be more or less the same with 1, 2 or 3 threads? 
Why does it increase?

This is the method that runs N threads:

```
private static void runThreads(List<int[][]> graphs, int nThreads) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    Collection<Callable<String>> callables = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                for(int[][] graph: graphs) {
                    FloydWarshall f = new FloydWarshall(graph);
                    f.checkConsistency();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<Future<String>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables);

    executor.shutdown();

    long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Total time: " + totalTime  + " ms");        
}
```

Comment: Maybe IO is the bottleneck? Just a guess.

Comment: Looks like you run the algorithm n times where n is the number of thread. So more threads more time.

Comment: @C-Otto That is my guess too. Is that a limitation of JVM or what?

Comment: @zhh Those are submitted as Runnables to the executor. In theory increasing `n` should not cause longer execution time, provided the hardware scales along.

Comment: @zhh I run the algorithm based on the size of List<int[][]> graphs that it is always the same.

Comment: @C-Otto Yes, the execution time should be the same whatever ```n``` is if we ignore the overhead of for loop and the creation of new threads.

Comment: If you have n threads you will have to run the algorithm n times. So the execution time should not be less. And the overhead increase when the number of thread increase, so your execution time will be longer. For example, if you have 3 threads, you will have to write to file 3 times.

Comment: you're measuring the time outside of the for loop which doesn't really make sense

Comment: @Lino Why? I wait for the executors to terminate with "while (!executor.isTerminated())". What I get is the total execution time.

Comment: When you listed the executiontimes, you didn't mean that the first thread executes `~483 ms` the second `~615 ms` and so on? Did you mean that 2 Threads together have `~615 ms` execution time?

Comment: @zhh I don't write to file. I read the files and I execute N threads. What I want to to is to see what happens if you run N threads that are exactly the same and the result I expect is that the time is more or less the same.

Comment: @Lino Yes, sorry. ~483 ms is the total execution time with 1 Thread. ~615 ms is the total execution time with two Threads. ~741 ms is the total execution time with three Threads.

Comment: OK I know what you want to do and for a more precise measurement you can timing in the begin and end of ```run``` method. That is timing for each thread and the total time = the last finish - the first start.

Comment: You are sharing the int[][] between threads, so there is going to be some contention for resources. Also your `while(!executor.isTerminated())` is a horrible design, try using invokeAll which will wait for completion.

Comment: Also, how many cores do you have? Your while loop is swamping one core, then you're processing the tasks by dividing up the remaining cores among the number of threads.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the hint. I changed the code in the post with invokeAll. I have 4 cores. So, can the problem be the int[][] variable that is shared?

Comment: you also maybe want to start measuring time right before the `invokeAll` call

Comment: @Lino. Thanks. That was a mistake. I edited the code.

Comment: just out of curiosity, did that affect anything when measuring the time?

Comment: That can be an issue, What are the new times you get? Also, when you say four cores, do you mean 4 actual cores, or 2 cores with hyperthreading that makes it appear as 4 course. Then, also if you watch the system monitor, are all four threads staying hot? Finally do you have a profiler, it could tell you the times for method calls and you can see if the actual method calls are taking longer.

Comment: @Lino New timings with 1000x1000 matrices. 1 Thread: ~43519 ms, 2 Threads: ~42332 ms, 3 Threads: ~62702 ms

Comment: @matt so could a solution be to read the files inside the call() method (so every thread reads them and has its own variable) and not in the main() before running the threads?

Comment: A solution to what? What is the problem? If you want every thread to have it's own copy of the int[][]'s to see if that is causing a slowdown, then make a copies. Which actual processor are you using?

Comment: Another suggestion is to look at the right way to do benchmarking, because simply measuring time is not enough, you have to take jvm warmup, jit optimization and a lot more into account

Comment: @matt I have the intel 4288U (2 cores, 4 threads). New timings with copies: 1 Thread: 47603ms, 2 Threads: 45568ms, 3 Threads: 66214 ms. No the times of the first two threads are always more or less the same. They goes up just with 3 threads.

Comment: Your processor only has 2 cores, so you cannot exceed 2 cpu bound processes. The hyperthreading is really good at switching contexts, but it doesn't actually give you 4x's the processing power.

Comment: @matt Right. I will try with a 4 core processor. The problem was the variable being shared. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnF I am pretty sure the original "problem" was that while loop that was swamping one of your threads. The variable being shared didn't seem to have much of an effect. But, I really encourage you to use a profiler, then you can see if the time it takes to execute a method is changing or not.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments by @C-Otto you're running the task multiple times on multiple threads:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) { // <-- n threads are created
    System.out.println("Running thread #" + (i+1));
    executor.submit(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
             for(int[][] graph: graphs) { // <-- operating on the whole list
                  FloydWarshall f = new FloydWarshall(graph);
                  f.checkConsistency();
             }
        }
    });         
}
```

So the behaviour your seeing is just as expected when looking at your code. Because you're just creating `n` threads which all execute at the same time the whole list. The execution time drawback comes from the extra load the JVM must handel (e.g. creating a new Thread, executing the whole algorithm and so on).

But what you probably wanted is to balance the load onto `n` threads, so each Thread is only working with a small part of the whole (`1/nth`).

So you probably need to define some logic to split up the source (e.g. `Spliterator`, `ForkJoinPool` or `Streams`) and then measure the time again.

Comment: I know that I could split the List of matrix and give each different piece to a Thread. What I'm trying to understand is why the total time goes up If every thread runs the same piece of code. I/O bottleneck or what?

Comment: @JohnF I'm assuming that the algorithm uses a lot of the CPU to check the consistency, so you're probably having a hardware bottleneck